# Why is sqflite retaining open database reference on hot reload

Tags: flutter, android-emulator, sqflite

I have an app that checks for an sqflite db file in the app storage directory and if it is present, blows away the file and creates a new one and then opens it for the remainder of the app life.  What I have noticed is that hot restart fails with sql exceptions because it still sees the database as open somewhere in memory even though all my references are blown away due to the restart. This seems like a bug because I have no way to control the closing of that database unless I try to make sure it is closed if the application is killed.  Is this by design?  Is there a standard way to approach it?

I noticed this related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61599995/flutter-sqflite-database-unstable-after-hot-reload/61611548#61611548)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further testing it looks like 1 way to handle this is to check for the existence of the file.  If the file exists, go ahead and open it using sqflite's openDatabase method.  Then immediately close it.  Then delete the file using io file delete method.  Then you can create a new database file using the openDatabase method.  This solution is maybe a little more expensive than I had hoped but it is working.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption and investigation are correct. With bad words, what happens during hot restart is that the dart environment is restarted while the native world is still running and for sqlite that means that open databases remain opened with no easy way to know that from the dart side.

The hot-restart hack in place in sqflite is meant mainly to handle hotrestart even if you are in a sqlite transaction. Without this hack, it should happen what you describe in your scenario. That is said `deleteDatabase` should be used instead of removing manually the file.

In theory, this should be handled in `openDatabase` and `deleteDatabase`.

Can you confirm that you are indeed using `deleteDatabase`? If yes, in the mean time your workaround is safe and reporting an issue on sqflite for investigation would be great. Thanks!

Comment: I am not using deleteDatabase.  I have been removing the file using the io package File class.