# I am trying to run two await and a navigator.push in an async function, and i got this error in flutter

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, async-await, navigator

Error:
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
E/flutter ( 6342): At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
E/flutter ( 6342): To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
E/flutter ( 6342): #0      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup. (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3864:9)
E/flutter ( 6342): #1      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3878:6)
E/flutter ( 6342): #2      Element.findAncestorStateOfType (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3926:12)
E/flutter ( 6342): #3      Navigator.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2706:40)
E/flutter ( 6342): #4      Navigator.pop (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2592:15)
E/flutter ( 6342): #5      NotificationDialog.checkAvailabilityOfRide (package:drivers_app/Notifications/notificationDialog.dart:240:20)
E/flutter ( 6342):

Snippet of my code:

```
 void checkAvailabilityOfRide(context) async {
    
      var rideRequestId = await rideRequestRef.once();
           ...
      var dataSnapShot2 =  await newRequestsRef.child(rideRequestId.value).once();
           ...
     Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> 
      NewRideScreen(rideDetails: rideDetails)));
         ...
   }
```

Updated Code:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Dialog(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)),
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  elevation: 1.0,
  child: Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
    width: double.infinity,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
    ),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        SizedBox(height: 30.0),
        Image.asset("images/taxi.png", width: 120.0,),
        SizedBox(height: 18.0,),
        Text("New Ride Request", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Brand-Bold", fontSize: 18.0,),),
        SizedBox(height: 30.0),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [

              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Image.asset("images/pickicon.png", height: 16.0, width: 16.0,),
                  SizedBox(width: 20.0,),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(child: Text(rideDetails.pickup_address, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),)),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 15.0),

              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Image.asset("images/desticon.png", height: 16.0, width: 16.0,),
                  SizedBox(width: 20.0,),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(child: Text(rideDetails.dropOff_address, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),)),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 15.0),

            ],
          ),
        ),

        SizedBox(height: 20.0),
        Divider(height: 2.0,color: Colors.black, thickness: 2.0,),
        SizedBox(height: 8.0),

        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [

              FlatButton(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                    side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
                color: Colors.white,
                textColor: Colors.red,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                onPressed: ()
                {
                  assetsAudioPlayer.stop();
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Text(
                  "Cancel".toUpperCase(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              SizedBox(width: 25.0),

              RaisedButton(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                    side: BorderSide(color: Colors.green)),
                onPressed: ()
                {
                  assetsAudioPlayer.stop();
                  checkAvailabilityOfRide0(context);
                  checkAvailabilityOfRide(context);
                },

                color: Colors.green,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                child: Text("Accept".toUpperCase(),
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ),

        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

```
Future<void> checkAvailabilityOfRide(context) async {
   var rideRequestId = await rideRequestRef.once();
   Navigator.push(context);
   String theRideId = "";
   var dataSnapShot2 =  await newRequestsRef.child( rideRequestId.value).once();
   /*... process...*/

   if(theRideId == rideDetails.ride_request_id && r2canShare) {
   rideRequestRef.set("accepted");
   AssistantMethods.disableHomeTabLiveLocationUpdates();
   Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
   NewRideScreen(rideDetails: rideDetails)));
 }
   else if(theRideId == 'cancelled') {
   displayToastMessage("Ride has been Cancelled.", context);
   }
   else if(theRideId == 'cancelled') {
   displayToastMessage("Ride has been time out.", context);
   }
   else if(r2canShare == false) {
   assetsAudioPlayer.stop();
   displayToastMessage("Rider 2 cannot shared ride, out of range.", context);
   }
   else {
   displayToastMessage("Ride not exists.", context);
   }
```

}

altered code:

```
  void checkAvailabilityOfRide(context)async{
    var dataSnapShot2 =  await newRequestsRef.child( (await 
      rideRequestRef.once()).value).once();
    Navigator.pop(context);
    String theRideId = "";
    /*... process...*/
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61424636/flutter-looking-up-a-deactivated-widgets-ancestor-is-unsafe)

Comment: Still the same error, ....Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.

Comment: Please show the context where you call this function, providing enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @PatrickO'Hara please see the code I added

Comment: The edit does not show the context where the function is called, i.e. the `Widget` that calls it.

Comment: @PatrickO'Hara I added the widget, please see on the edit.

Comment: OK, I have reproduced your code as a test, but it works OK. Note that I had to remove the line `Navigator.push(context);` which is invalid. I see from another answer that it was previously `Navigator.pop(context);` which causes the error that you first reported. So what code are you actually testing now?

Comment: @PatrickO'Hara I tried another way, and it somehow fix my problem, i combined the two await into one. And The navigator.pop already works. Originally it was two await , I queried  twice  in the database and must show the screen (Navigator.pop) but it fails, that's why i tried that technique and it works. See my altered Code. But the only thing is I cannot anymore access the RideRequestId, it would help in showing a toast message if the driver accepts or rejects the request of firstRider. But its okay atleast it could already navigate and pop the screen.

Comment: I did some experiments, I will document them with some suggestions in an answer. You should be ok having multiple `await` statements before the `pop`, but do not have one after the `Navigator.pop` and before the `Navigator.push`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nin Yu, Past some days I got the same error I tried to fix using @Patrick answer, but that didn't work too sometimes. When I closely debug it I found I was calling method containing Navigator multiple times. So sometimes I got context and I pass safely to the next screen and some it throws an error. I would suggest debug method and check whether it occurence.

Answer (score 1):

As the poster found (see comments on question), the error is caused by having an async `await` execute between the `Navigator.pop` and `Navigator.push`. I guess the `await` gives Flutter time to destroy the current screen before the `push`, which causes the exception on the `push`.

Note that Flutter provides various ways to pop and push at the same time, which avoid the chance of having intervening code: `pushReplacement` and `pushReplacementNamed` replace the current screen with a new one, and `popAndPushNamed` does the same with different animation.

Comment: thanks for your advice,  i appreciate your effort in responding to my problems, I hope you could help me more in the future 